# How to properly pass InputStream to another constructor? (Java)

Tags: java, constructor, autocloseable

In the code below I try to access my other constructor that takes a InputStream...
However I need to somehow close this stream to avoid resource leaks. If I try to put a try catch around, it will complain that the constructor call isn't the first statement. Is there any way to pass this InputStream without any potential risks?

```
public Input(File source) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(new FileInputStream(source));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make this class implement `AutoClosable` and make sure you use it within a try-with-resource:

```
public class Input extends SomeClass implements AutoCloseable {
    public Input(File source) throws FileNotFoundException {
        this(new FileInputStream(source));
    }
    @Override 
    public void close() {
        someMethodThatClosesInnerResource();
    }
}
```

You can then use the object like this:

```
try (Input input = new Input(source)) {
    ...
}
```

If you're concerned that the super constructor will throw an exception, then you might want to add a builder method to protect against early exceptions:

```
public class Input extends SomeClass implements AutoCloseable {
    public static Input createInput(File source) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(source);
        try {
            return new Input(inputstream);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            inputstream.close();
            throw e;
        }
    }
    private Input(FileInputStream source)  {
        this(source);
    }
    @Override 
    public void close() {
        someMethodThatClosesInnerResource();
    }
}
```

You should then still use this as a try-with-resource:

```
try (Input input = Input.createInput(source)) {
    ...
}
```

Notice in the builder method you have to protect against all exceptions... this is not great practice as now you have to make the method throw a general exception... or use a utility to throw silently. You can avoid this issues by just not having the constructor create the `FileInputStream`. Instead just inject the `FileInputStream` into your class and create it in the try-with-resource as well. This will safely allow both objects to be closed in the event of a ctor exception:

```
try (
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(source);
    Input input = new Input(stream)
) {
    ...
}
```